# Hide password field in GET but not POST in Django REST Framework where depth=1 in serializer

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have 2 models : User & UserSummary. UserSummary has a foreign key to User. I just noticed that if I set `depth= 1` within `UserSummarySerializer`, the password field is included in the output. It's hashed, but it would still be best to exclude this field.

To hide the password field, I've just set the user field explicitly in the serializer, just like this :

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A serializer for our user profile objects."""

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
       extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
        exclude = ('groups', 'last_login', 'is_superuser', 'user_permissions', 'created_at')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create and return a new user."""

        user = models.User(
            email = validated_data['email'],
            firstname = validated_data['firstname'],
            lastname = validated_data['lastname'],
            mobile = validated_data['mobile']
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user


class UserSummarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.UserSummary
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

The downside of this way of doing is that, the field password is not available anymore on the POST request when creating a new user.

How could I hide the `password` field on the GET request of UserSummary but display it in the POST request of User ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is complicated when you put all the function serializer to one, I would create a `UserCreateSerializer` in this scenario:

```
class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A serializer for our user profile objects."""

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'email', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'mobile'] # there what you want to initial.

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create and return a new user."""

        user = models.User(
            email = validated_data['email'],
            firstname = validated_data['firstname'],
            lastname = validated_data['lastname'],
            mobile = validated_data['mobile']
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

Then you can use the `UserCreateSerializer` in your `UserCreateAPIView`.

Answer (score 18):

The trick here is to include the 'password' field in the "fields" tuple so that password shows in BOTH 'GET' and 'POST', and then add 'extra_kwargs' to force 'password' field ONLY to appear in 'POST' form. Code as below:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email',
              'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'password',)

        # These fields are displayed but not editable and have to be a part of 'fields' tuple
        read_only_fields = ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',)

        # These fields are only editable (not displayed) and have to be a part of 'fields' tuple
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'min_length': 4}}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        rep = super(UserSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
        rep.pop('password', None)
        return rep
```

Answer (score 1):

To Make your password to not show password, you need to change style like following-

```
password = serializers.CharField(
    style={'input_type': 'password'}
    )
```

That's it. I hope it helps.

Comment: How to also clear the fields after successful POST request

Comment: That can be done via HTML/Javascript not by django.

Answer (score 1):

Make Changes in Serializers.py file

```
password = serializers.CharField( 
           style={'input_type': 'password'},
           min_length=6, 
           max_length=68, 
           write_only=True)
```