# How to skip or remove password field in simplejwt token authentication in django rest framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

My requirement is, I don't wanted to enter password in simplejwt token authentication. I have added one extra field in the authentication by inheriting the `init()` method of **TokenObtainPairSerializer**
as per my requrements.

Currently, I am passing `None` as in password field but still its showing to user (djnago admin portal). What I want is, I don't wanted to show the password field to user while authentication using simplejwt.

below is my code,

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer

class CustomSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields[self.username_field] = serializers.CharField()
        self.fields['password'] = PasswordField(default=None)
        self.fields['extra'] = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        pass
```

Is there any ways to set PasswordField as unusable so it wont show to user?

Comment: You can check this question for hidden field.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48480972/hide-password-field-in-get-but-not-post-in-django-rest-framework-where-depth-1-i

Comment: Thanks @YunusEmreCevik for the information. Anyway, that is not working for me. Is there anyway I can fully  override the parent class method?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yes @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 I have solved the problem using del. So it wont ask you the password. How to use,  `del self.fields['password']`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62066402/5675325

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 I have answered it in details.

Answer (score 4):

I have followed the below mentioned process to solve the problem,

1. Override the `TokenObtainPairSerializer` class `__init__` method like below,
2. Use `del self.fields['password']`, so It wont ask you the password and add whatever fields you want.

`class CustomSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields[self.username_field] = serializers.CharField()
        del self.fields['password']`

This works really well. There is a almost same question I have answered, You can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62066402/drf-simplejwt-remove-password-and-add-date-field) for more knowledge.

Let me know if anyone have better solution of this problem.